# Newtons method in C++

Tags: c++, newtons-method

Hi I have checked numerous other questions but can't seem to figure out why my implementation will not converge. I keep getting  the "Error, no convergence" part of my program even when I enter the root.

The function is y = x^2 - 1

Here is the code:

```
// Newton sqaure root finder function

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
using namespace std;

// Enter an initial guess x
cout << "Enter an initial guess: ";
double x;
cin >> x;


// Define & initialize the error, tolerance and iteration variables
double tol = 1e-12;
cout << 1e-12;
double error = tol + 1; 
int it = 0;
int max_it = 100;

// Define the x1 variable to hold the latest result (root approximation)
double x1;

// Start while loop with guess x to find the root
while (error > tol && it < max_it)
{
    x1 = x + (x*x-1) / (2*x);
    error = fabs(x1 - x);
    x = x1;
    it++;
    cout << error << endl;
}

if (error <= tol)
{
    cout << "The root is " << x << endl;
} 
else
{
    cout << "Error, no convergence" << endl;
}

cin.get();
cin.get(); 

return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a perfect program to use your debugger on.  You would probably have found the answer in the time it took you to make this post.

Comment: I apologize but I do not know how to use the debugger. Can you link me a website or something where it says how it is done? Thank you!

Comment: This strongly depends on what platform you write your code on / what compiler you use.

Comment: I am using visual basic studio 13 (windows 10)

Comment: @DoubleOseven https://www.google.com, and it's just Visual Studio, not Basic.

Comment: Thanks you for all your answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in the formula

```
x1 = x + (x*x-1) / (2*x);
```

it should be

```
x1 = x - (x*x-1) / (2*x);
```

You may see it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots